# Show an Anchor tag in an ASP.Net page with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, anchor

I've got an ASP.Net page in which I have an html anchor tag and I've set the visible property to false.  I want to make it visible with JQuery, but can't seem to get it to work.  I've tried to use the selector for the anchor tag itself, and also a class selector, but neither has any effect.  Here is the markup for the anchor tag:

```
<a runat="server" class="reg" visible="false" id="RegisterSoftwareTab" href="../RegisterSoftware.aspx">Register Software</a>
```

And here is the JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').attr("visible", "true");
        $('a').show();
        $('.reg').attr("visible", "true");
        $('.reg').show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show html generated for that tag, please?

Comment: Nikita, I think that may be the problem, I went to view the page source in the browser, and there is no html for that link. It looks like the visible="false" parameter causes it to not render the html.  I think I'll try changing the html tag to an asp tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visible` is not a correct attribute to use; it isn't defined by the HTML standard. You can use the `Visible` attribute only on an ASP.NET control like the `asp:Button`; `Visible="false"` will then be rendered to a `style="display:none"`, which is HTML compliant.

If you want to hide your element using a normal HTML tag, try to use the `display` CSS property directly within the HTML tag:

```
<a runat="server" class="reg" style="display:none;"  id="RegisterSoftwareTab" href="../RegisterSoftware.aspx">Register Software</a>
```

What the `show()` method does is to switch the element's style to `display:inline;`, so in this case you shall call only `$('.reg').show()` or `$('a').show()`, without having to change the `display` CSS property directly using the `attr()` method:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `visible` is an ASP.Net web control property, not an HTML one :)

Comment: Yes, I know; I indirectly mentioned this in the very first line, but then realized that it's a good idea to mention its usage on an ASP.NET control :) I changed my answer to include this little hint, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `style` to `none` for the anchor tag:

```
<a runat="server" class="reg" style="display: none;" id="RegisterSoftwareTab" href="../RegisterSoftware.aspx">Register Software</a>
```

Then to show it, use `$('a').show();`